# Is REST just a theory to create a good api?

Tags: rest

I came to through lot of articles and finally I understood that its just a theory to create a good API is that correct or I am getting confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct "REST IS JUST A THEORY" with 6 guiding principals of Roy Fielding and those constraints are to get maximum advantages of web service and web service is nothing but an API

REST + API = REST API

Comment: Where I can get the original documentation for this?

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm